# In Emacs how can I use "Other-window" from an elisp script?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Everytime I use other-window I get the error:

Wrong number of arguments: #, 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(other-window 1)
```

The argument "specifies the number of windows to skip, starting with the
selected window, before making the selection."

Answer (score 4):

I recommend reading [An Introduction To Programming in Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/index.html), as well as learning about <kbd>M-x describe-function</kbd> (aka <kbd>C-h f</kbd>) which will give you documentation for a given function.

Comment: The documentation says: "Select the ARG'th different window on this frame. All windows on current frame are arranged in a cyclic order. This command selects the window ARG steps away in that order. A negative ARG moves in the opposite order. If the optional second argument ALL_FRAMES is non-nil, cycle through all frames." This is really bad user documentation in my case as I couldn't follow it

Comment: @Zubair The point of the documentation, in this case, was to show you that there was an ARGUMENT that was required.  That is shown clearly by the fact that `count` is before the `&optional`.  That was all you needed to understand.  And the fact that you couldn't understand it doesn't mean it is bad user documentation.

Comment: Good point. Is there an explanation of how to read the documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this shortcut: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`other-window`

```
(other-window COUNT &optional ALL-FRAMES)
```

You have one non-optional argument. And information on what arguments are, and what they do.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why it doesn't work. I just do

```
(other-window 1)
```